# как правильно передать данные в список?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Суть в том что создается словарь со списком машин, которые нужно распределить по nodes, но на каждом из 5ти индексов `nodes` не должно быть повторяющихся имен машин.
ИЗ апи приходят такие машины:

```
#welcome-php-2.node.eu.consul
#aff-java-1.node.eu.consul
#aff-java-3.node.eu.consul
#tgbot-go-1.node.eu.consul
и тд.
```

```
def get_next_hostname(current_hostname):
    parts = current_hostname.split('-')
    index = int(parts[-1].split('.')[0])
    new_name = '{}-{}-{}.node.eu.consul'.format(parts[0], parts[1], index + 6)
    return new_name

def get_service_name(current_hostname):
    parts = current_hostname.split('-')
    service_type = '{}'.format(parts[0])
    return service_type

response = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1/asl_real.json')
asl_vms = json.loads(response.text)
groupped_vms = dict()
nodes = {1:dict(),2:dict(),3:dict(),4:dict(),5:dict()}

for vm in asl_vms:
    first_part = get_service_name(vm['name'])
    if first_part not in groupped_vms:
        groupped_vms[first_part] = []
    else:
        groupped_vms[first_part].append(vm) 

for node in nodes:
    for vm_first_part_key in groupped_vms:
        vm_group = groupped_vms[vm_first_part_key]
        if len(vm_group) == 0:
            continue
        vm = vm_group.pop()
        vm_res = {'first_part_name:' : first_part, 'os:' : vm['distribution']['description'],'memory:' : vm['memory'],'cpu:' : vm['cpu'],'cpuNumber:' : vm['cpuNumber'],'disk:' : vm['disk']}
        nodes[node][get_next_hostname(vm['name'])] = vm_res
print(json.dumps(nodes))
```

В данном фрагменте 3 из 9ти машин, что приходят из АПИ, изчезают из-за параметра `groupped_vms[first_part]`, т.е. каждое первое имя записывается в этот `[first_part]`, а остальные уже нормально попадают в итоговый вывод. Но вот как записать иначе не могу никак понять!
если убирать этот параметр и записывать его внуть `groupped_vms = [first_part]`, то ругается на:

```
    vm_res = {'first_part_name:' : first_part, 'os:' : vm['distribution']['description'],'memory:' : vm['memory'],'cpu:' : vm['cpu'],'cpuNumber:' : vm['cpuNumber'],'disk:' : vm['disk']}
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

UDP:
дописал, что приход из апи тут:

```
[
  {
      "id" : 799,
      "name" : "welcome-php-2.node.eu.consul",
      "internalId" : "vm799",
      "tenantId" : 5,
      "memory" : 1536,
      "disk" : 8192,
      "cpu" : 2,
      "cpuNumber" : 2,
      "bandwidth" : 100,
      "tariffId" : 1,
      "ipAddresses" : [ ],
      "privateIpAddress" : "10.192.4.68",
      "state" : "VIR_DOMAIN_RUNNING",
      "timeAdded" : "2022-08-10T18:29:50+03:00",
      "backupPolicy" : {
        "quantity" : 1,
        "frequency" : 72
      },
      "distribution" : {
        "id" : 6,
        "name" : "DEBIAN",
        "description" : "Debian 11.3 x64",
        "bitness" : 64
      },
      "accessUsers" : [ "am@adguard.com", "d.naumov@adguard.com" ],
      "publicKeys" : [ {
        "id" : 3,
        "name" : "root@puppet5.node.flops.consul",
        "type" : "ECDSA",
        "installed" : true
      }, {
        "id" : 1,
        "name" : "sc",
        "type" : "ECDSA",
        "installed" : true
      } ],
      "host" : "172.16.4.23",
      "nodeId" : 4
  },
```

Comment: Покажите как выглядит собственно `json`

Comment: @CrazyElf ,  дописал в конце вопроса вывод одной из машин из АПИ.
в целом собираю оттуда такую инфу: `vm_res = {'first_part_name:' : first_part, 'os:' : vm['distribution']['description'],'memory:' : vm['memory'],'cpu:' : vm['cpu'],'cpuNumber:' : vm['cpuNumber'],'disk:' : vm['disk']}`

Comment: Покажите метод `get_service_name` что делает. С моими догадками такая ошибка не выходит

Comment: А вообще оберните проблемный кусок в try/except и при выпадении исключения сделайте печать `vm`, будет многое понятнее

Comment: @CrazyElf дописал две функции, что вызываю в коде. По поводу второго сообщения, не понял что имеется в виду. Это как?) :/

Comment: У меня с вашими данными этот код не падает. Видимо, есть какая-то часть `json`, имеющая несколько другую структуру. Попробуйте чтобы проще было поставить перед той строчкой с присваиванием `print(vm)` и покажите последнее, что будет напечатано перед ошибкой.

Comment: @CrazyElf , я думаю, вы не поняли. в данном варианте он не падает, но так первая машина каждого имени будет записана в тег `groupped_vms[first_part]`, и в итоговом выводе их из-за этого нет. Я пробовал убирать тег, как описал в вопросе, но тогда выдает ошибку. 
Т.Е. из 4ех имен `aff`: первое пишется в тег, а остальные только попадут в итоговый спискок, и так со всеми, соответственно

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение: не заметил сам, что `for vm in asl_vms:` на первой итерации некуда записывать машины. Добавил это: `groupped_vms[first_part] = [vm]` Теперь работает.